# Converting date from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, date

I'm having difficulty working with dates in Python and Javascript.

```
>>> d = date(2004, 01, 01)
>>> d
datetime.date(2004, 1, 1)
>>> time.mktime(d.timetuple())
1072944000.0
```

Then, in Javascript (data sent over Ajax):

```
>>> new Date(1072944000.0)
Tue Jan 13 1970 02:02:24 GMT-0800 (PST) {}
```

I'm confused. Shouldn't the Javascript date be the same as the one that I entered in Python? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Javascript's `Date()` takes milliseconds as an argument. Python's uses seconds. You have to multiply by 1,000.

Answer (score 25):

Python:

```
import datetime, time
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
for_js = int(time.mktime(d.timetuple())) * 1000
```

Then in JS:

```
new Date({{ for_js }});
```

In Flask you can do:

```
@app.template_filter('date_to_millis')
def date_to_millis(d):
    """Converts a datetime object to the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch."""
    return int(time.mktime(d.timetuple())) * 1000
```

And then do:

```
new Date({{ current_user.created|date_to_millis }});
```

Answer (score 13):

Python is returning the time since the epoch in seconds. Javascript takes the time in milliseconds. Multiply the time by 1000 before passing it to `Date()` and you should get the expected result.

```
new Date(1072944000.0 * 1000)
```